# New at arrays: returning array values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to input 4 values into an array, subtract 5 from each value, and print out the new values.

I always have issues with correctly calling methods and returning outputs from methods into the right place ie. under `System.out.println`.

I'm also not sure if my subtraction mechanism works :

```
public class TestCase{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] user1 = {1,2,3,4};
        int []normalizedNumbers = compareUser(int [] user1);
        {
            System.out.println(normalizedNumbers[n]); //this is where I want my end result
        }
    }

    public static int []compareUsers(int [] user1){

        int [] normalizingStuff = new int[user1];
        int n = 0;
        for (n=0; n<user1;n++){
            normalizingStuff [n] = user1 [n]-5;//subtracting 5 from values at each index of user1   
        }
        return normalizingStuff;//this is what i want printed out
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the loop for System.out.println? There is no `n` in `main()` How did it even compile?

Comment: and it is not `n < user1`, its `n < user1.length`. You need to go through the Java Basics.

Comment: Good for you that you ask, but these are the very basics of Java, try to google some elemetary tutorial :P

Answer (score 0):

Few problems here:

First you're not calling your `compareUser` the good way. You just need to pass your array as an argument (without the type declaration):

```
int []normalizedNumbers = compareUser(user1);
```

Then if you want to print the values you gonna have to iterate on your array with a `for` loop for example and print `user1[i]` on each iteration.

In your `compareUser()` (watch out you have `compareUser()` and `compareUsers()`), you probably want the size of your array for the affectation and in the for loop. You can get it with `user1.length`.

The program as it is now should give you a lot of errors, so if you're working with a good IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ...), I suggest you read carefully the error message you get, most of the times it gives you the answer to your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, I'll try to fix this...but no I'm not using Eclipse or anything so maybe I should start